# How to display the sum of the rest of the Transaction types

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

I'm making a list of the total amount of each of these Transaction types for that day I made a case statement for each one according to the rules I was given but I need to display the sum of the other Transactions that are not specified

```
  var flagged = from c in db.vw_BMO_Daily
  group c by c.DatePosted into dateGroup
  select new AccountingSum()
  {

      Date = dateGroup.Key,
      Year = dateGroup.Key.Year,
      Month = dateGroup.Key.Month,
      Store = dateGroup.Select(x=>x.Store_Id),
      BridgeLoan = dateGroup.Sum(x => x.TransactionType == "Miscellaneous Debit" && x.TransactionDescription.Contains("Bridge Loan") ? x.DebitAmount : 0),
      FloorPlanPayout = dateGroup.Sum(x => x.TransactionType == "Miscellaneous Debit" && !x.TransactionDescription.Contains("Bridge Loan") ? x.DebitAmount : 0),
      FloorPlanEquity = dateGroup.Sum(X => X.TransactionType == "Miscellaneous Credit"? X.CreditAmount:0),
      ZBA_Debit_Credit = dateGroup.Sum(x => x.TransactionType.Contains("Zero Balance") ? x.DebitAmount + x.CreditAmount : 0),
      ACH = dateGroup.Sum(x => x.TransactionType.Contains("ACH") ? x.CreditAmount + x.DebitAmount : 0),
      IncomingWires = dateGroup.Sum(x => x.TransactionType == "Incoming Money Transfer" ? x.CreditAmount : 0),
      AccountAnalysis = dateGroup.Sum(x => x.TransactionType == "Account Analysis Fee" ? x.DebitAmount : 0),
      CheckPaid = dateGroup.Sum(x => x.TransactionType == "Check Paid" ? x.DebitAmount : 0),
      DebitReversal = dateGroup.Sum(x => x.TransactionType == "Debit Reversal" ? x.CreditAmount : 0)

 };
```

The last 2 transactions sums "CheckPaid" and "DebitReversal" should be going into an "Other" column

Comment: The question should be more clear. What "Other" column?  Is it just the sum of CheckPaid and DebitReversal?

Comment: so you want 2 values in other column?
you can create a Tuple on fly.
Other = (dateGroup.Sum(x => x.TransactionType == "Check Paid" ? x.DebitAmount : 0),
       dateGroup.Sum(x => x.TransactionType == "Debit Reversal" ? x.CreditAmount : 0)
)

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out I just made the sum of the 2 Transaction type on the class

```
 public decimal Other { get { return CheckPaid + DebitReversal; } set { } }
```